# Displaying UTM basemap and blocks

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, utm

Im using arcmaps 10.1 and i have to imput pen points off a buch of old maps into arcmaps i have everything in order in arc maps but need help displaying the utm zones, basemaps, blocks, possibly sub-blocks as well. Having a shapefile with that all in it would be nice or if theres a simple way to get this to display in data view that would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please define "blocks and sub-blocks".  These have multiple meanings based on the context.

Comment: Well as you knonk utm zones are devided into basemaps that are 10km x 10km then base maps are devided further into blocks that are 1km x 1km then into sub-blocks that are 100m x 100m. This is what i wanto display as a grid in data view

Answer (score 3):

A shapefile with the UTM zones is included (along with other referencee systems) in the install of ArcGIS.  It can be found here

> C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Reference Sysytems

There's other goodies in the the "Desktop 10.0 (or 10.1, probably 9.3 too)"

I'm not sure which basemaps you are talking about, but the build in basemaps are located at

> file>add data>add basemap

Ok, I see what you are asking for, which is the Military Grid Reference System (MGRS), that is based on UTM.  UTM is broken into zones like 16T, but MGRS goes a few steps further.  [This](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/coordsys/gislayers/gislayers.html) should be what you're looking for:

Also, [here](http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/fieldmethods/utmsystem.htm) is some good information on UTM and MGRS (They're calling it the NATO system here)